# MIPS assembly code--shifting left using an 8-bit shift count in memory

Tags: assembly, mips, bit-shift

This is a problem for homework but I'm thoroughly stumped. These problems should have a straight-forward solution, and I'm wondering if the teacher may have mistakenly made this problem like this. But here is the exact text:

"Write a program called LSHIFT to shift logically the 16-bit contents of memory locations 0x10010010 and 0x10010011 left according to the 8-bit shift count stored in memory location 0x10010012."

Here is my problem. To logically shift bits, MIPS only has two instructions: sll, which takes an immediate value (therefore I can't use it, right?) and sllv, which take a value stored in a register, but uses only 5 bits. This means that using sllv, I can only shift the bits a maximum of 32 places (2^5) but the problem wants me to write a program that will shift up to 256 places (2^8 for 8 bit shift count). I can only think of two ways around this:

1) Use multiplication instead

2) Break the 8-bit number into 8 pieces and run 8 separate instructions (e.g. if the shift count is 256, shift left 32, 8 times).

I also want to double-check--bits can be shifted into other memory locations, correct? Or are they restricted to their 32-bit, %4 memory addresses? As an example, will a 5-bit shift of count 11111 do the same thing as an 8-bit shift of count 11111111 because the bits are restricted to the same 32 bits of memory space?

Correct me if I'm wrong on anything, because like I said, there should be a simple solution.

Comment: How can you tell, if the register has been shifted left more than 16 bits? (And how exactly are you planning to use multiplication?) To me this sounds like name dropping.

Comment: That was part of my question. I asked if there is a difference, i.e. IF you can tell (between bit shifts of greater and lesser count than the size of the memory space). From your comment I'm assuming you can't tell and I can use the sllv instruction.

Also, for what it's worth, I was thinking of replacing the shifts with multiplication--multiply by two once for each bit shift.

Answer (score 2):

`sllv` uses 5 bits to select one of the 32 registers. From there you are not limited to 5 bits of that register.

Take a look at this:

```
.text
main:

    addi $t0 $zero 1
    addi $t1 $zero 30
    sllv $a0 $t0 $t1

    li $v0 1
    syscall

    jr $ra
```

Outputs `1073741824` or 2^30.